# Hive Metastore 3 with Postgres backend - Schema

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

How do I get the schema for hive metastore with Postgres backend?

I see that the github repo: `https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/rel/release-3.1.2/metastore/scripts/upgrade/postgres` has files related to `2.3.0` and no further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that I can use the Schema Tool (CDP) to generate this. However I was also interested in making this part of some container/kubernetes bootstrap process and therefore was looking for a schema. I later learned that the bootstrap process can also be instrumented to use the Schema Tool which I hadn't thought of.

However, for anyone interested in more explicit schema sql. Here it is: [Schema for Hive Metasore](https://gist.github.com/pascals-ager/ac4be5ca885a14dac529884dcf51cb0b)